# Find $\int_1^2\int_{-1}^2xye^{xy^2}dxdy$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

$$\int_1^2\int_{-1}^2xye^{xy^2}dxdy$$

By using integration by parts, I got to the following point:

$$\int_1^2y^{-1}(e^{-y^2}-e^{2y^2})dy+\int_1^2y(2e^{2y^2}+e^{-y^2})dy$$

This seems quite a bit too complicated for a simple midweek maths problem sheet (especially since it's  for a Chemistry degree). Is there a simpler/easier way of doing it? If not, how do I carry on from what I have got to?

Comment: It would be better to switch the order of integration.

Comment: Use Pauls suggestion and note that $xye^{xy^{2}} = \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \bigg ( \frac{1}{2} e^{xy^{2}} \bigg )$

Comment: Why does that help?

Comment: $$\int \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \bigg ( \frac{1}{2} e^{xy^{2}} \bigg ) dy = \frac{1}{2} e^{xy^{2}} + C$$

Comment: I understand the result but I don't get why it helps in the context of this question

Comment: Because you have $$\int_{-1}^{2} \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \bigg ( \frac{1}{2} e^{xy^{2}} \bigg ) dy = \frac{1}{2} e^{xy^{2}} \biggr \lvert_{-1}^{2} $$ Then whatever the result is, integrate that with respect to $x$ and evaluate and theres your answer.

Comment: Sorry, that should be $$\frac{1}{2} e^{xy^{2}} \biggr \lvert_{1}^{2}$$ not $$\frac{1}{2} e^{xy^{2}} \biggr \lvert_{-1}^{2}$$.

Comment: By changing the order of integration, you can do a substitution $u=xy^2$.  Then $du=2xy\, dy$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\begin{eqnarray*}\int_{1}^{2}\int_{-1}^{2}xy\,e^{xy^2}\,dx\,dy &=& \int_{-1}^{2}\int_{1}^{2}xy\,e^{xy^2}\,dy\,dx =\frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^{2}\left(\left.e^{xy^2}\right|_{1}^{2}\right)\,dx\\&=&\frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^{2}\left(e^{4x}-e^{x}\right)\,dx=\color{red}{\frac{e^8-e^{-4}-e^2+e^{-1}}{2}}.\end{eqnarray*}$$